# How to add two line string in a excel cell using perl?

Tags: perl, excel, formatting

I wrote a perl scrips for witer data from csv file to excel sheet,i got the output file but the thing is i've header is bit lengther that data from below cell so i need to **split the lengthy string into multiple lines in the header cell itself**.can anybody help me?

Comment: Please clarify: You are creating a CSV file and open it in excel or you are directly edit an excel file?

Comment: @user1126070:no no dude this is fully automation process i have 5214 csv files!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`set_text_wrap`](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm#set_text_wrap%28%29) method of Excel::Writer::XLSX to do the word-wrapping.